# Windows error and python

Tags: python, popen

I'm working on a bit of code that is supposed to run an exe file inside a folder on my system and getting an error saying...

WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified.
Here's a bit of the code:

```
exepath = os.path.join(EXE file localtion)
exepath = '"' + os.path.normpath(exepath) + '"'
cmd = [exepath, '-el', str(el), '-n', str(z)]

print 'The python program is running this command:'
print cmd

process = Popen(cmd, stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
outputstring = process.communicate()[0]
```

I have imported subprocess and also from subprocess import *

For example, This is how my exe file location looks like in the first line of the code I show:

```
 exepath= os.path.join('/Program Files','next folder','next folder','blah.exe')
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you execute open(exepath), does it raise IOError (indicating that this file is inaccessible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly escape the space in the executable path

Comment: Yes, escape the space.  Also, what's the "/" doing there?  Doesn't windows use "\"?   Generally, don't use "Program Files" or "My Documents" for anything, and you'll be much happier.

Comment: / works just fine in system calls on Windows and did so even in real DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Besides properly escaping spaces and other characters that could cause problems (such as /), you can also use the 8 character old DOS paths.

For example, Program Files would be:

Progra~1 , making sure to append ~1 for the last two characters.

EDIT: You could add an r to the front of the string, making it a raw literal. Python would read the string character for character. Like this:

r " \Program files"

Comment: There should be two backslashes in front of Program Files, Stack overflow's editor is cutting one of them off.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you don't need to quote your executuable file path, like you do in the second line.

EDIT: Well, just grabbed nearby Windows box and tested this. Popen works the same regardless the path is quoted or not. So this is not an issue.

Comment: Just taking the quotes off the code above, It says 'blah' is not defined in my example

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no need to surround the path in quotation marks unless `cmd.exe` is involved in running the program.

In addition, you might want to use the environment variable `ProgramFiles` to find out the actual location of 'Program Files' because that depends on regional settings and can also be tweaked using TweakUI.

Comment: blah.exe is used in running the program. I'm feeding it a for statement with some numbers the blah.exe file uses.